# php under attack: how to detect if the client connection is closed?

Tags: php, nginx, connection, ddos

Nginx has custom response code '499' which means the client closed connection whilst the response sending wasn't completed yet.

We're under attack and it'd be useful to call die() if such case detected and not to waste any server resource further.

So, is there any way to detect?

Unsure whether the question should be here or at ServerFault.

Comment: The web server should handle those attacks (not letting the request even reach the PHP code), so I would say that it fits better over at Server Fault.

Comment: Not sure if it would solve your problem but it can help: [link](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module/issues/455)